# a continuous version of axiom of choice?

Tags: curves-and-surfaces

Let $L_t(s):S^1 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2(t\in [0,1])$ be a Jordan curve, $O(t)$ be its interior and $H(t,s)=L_t(s)$.
 If $H$ is a homotopy from $L_0(s)$ to$L_1(s)$, does there exist a continuous function $f:[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ s.t. $\forall t \in[0,1],f(t)\in O(t)$?

Answer (score 1):

By compactness one can replace the Jordan curves by a family of polygonal ones. The [cut locus $C(t)$ of the Jordan curve $L_t$](https://www.math.brown.edu/~res/M141/cut.pdf) is a rectifiable tree and one can choose the midpoint $m(t)$ of $C(t)$ is the value of $f$ at $t$, giving a continuous function with image in the interior of the Jordan curve for every $t$.

Comment: I believe the "tree" part but not the "rectifiable" part (imagine a narrow tentacle around $\sqrt{x}\sin(1/x)$) "Locally rectifiable" it is, but that's not enough to define the midpoint unless I misunderstand what the midpoint is.

Comment: @fedja I did not say the Jordan curve is rectifiable.  rather the cut locus is rectifiable as proved in the literature around Marcel Berger.  At any rate this is utterly irrelevant because for the purposes of this problem everything can be replaced by polygonal curves by compactness.

Comment: The cut locus of such a tentacle will go along the curve all the way to the origin, so it will have infinite length. What am I missing? As to the polygons, you'll have to show that the midpoint of the cut locus of the approximation is not just inside but deep inside the region, which is, probably, true, but not quite obvious.

Comment: @fedja, when you take a tubular neighborhood of a curve and then look for the cut locus of the boundary of the tubular epsilon-neighborhood, you won't necessarily get the original curve back except special cases when you have control on curvature and epsilon sufficiently small.

Comment: the "deep inside" is just a compactness argument.

Comment: I will still have a curve going ot the origin within the region and ***every*** such curve has infinite length.

Comment: Anyway if you think this is of interest we can try to write this up. My coauthor Kanovei is an expert on Jordan curve theorem.  Note that polygonal approximation is far from trivial, but it's been done.

Comment: Can you describe your example in more detail?

Comment: The boundary of $0\le x\le 1/2$, $\sqrt{x}\sin(1/x)-x^2\le y\le \sqrt{x}\sin(1/x)+x^2$, say

Comment: You are right, one has to approximate first.  The rectifiability is for more regular curves, perhaps $C^1$?

Comment: And now comes the problem: when approximating, the midpoint tends to gravitate towards the narrow winding part, so the "deep inside" story is no longer sheer compactness. I'm not saying it cannot be done, just that some pesky details have to be taken care of :-)

Comment: Let it gravitate if it wants.  The entire deformation is compact therefore the path of midpoints is at distance from the boundary that is bounded away from zero.

Comment: If you can do a ***continuous inner*** approximation, I agree. But is this always possible?

Comment: Perhaps we can continue via email?

Comment: @fedja One possible modification of the argument if one does not want to approximate by polygons is the following.  Consider the radius $r_t>0$ of a biggest ball that fits inside the curve $L_t$.  There are may be several such balls.  Then we consider the infimum of those $s_t>0$ for which there is a connected set in the complement of the $s_t$-neighborhood of $L_t$ and containing all of the maximal balls (with center at distance $r_t$ from $L_t$). Then we take a global minimum S of all the $s_t$ and work with this $S>0$ (positive by compactness).  We now work with the cut locus truncated at S

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple construction of the function $f$. It makes use of the Hausdorff metric on compact subsets of $\mathbb{R}^2$, defined by
$$d_H(A,B) = \inf\bigl\{r \in [0,\infty) \,\bigm|\, A \subset N(B,r), \, B \subset N(A,r)\bigr\}
$$ 
The image $L_t(S^1)$ is compact for each $t$. Continuity of the homotopy $H(t,s)$ implies continuity of the function $t \mapsto L_t(S^1)$ in the Hausdorff metric space on compact sets.

For each $t \in [0,1]$ make the following choices:

- pick $x_t \in O(t)$,
- then pick $r_t > 0$ so that $d(x_t,L_t(S^1)) > r_t$,
- then pick an open subset $I_t \subset [0,1]$ containing $t$ such that for all $s \in I_t$ we have $d_H(L_t(S^1),L_s(S^1)) < r_t$.

It follows from these choices that for each $t$ and each $s \in I_t$, the open ball $B(x_t,r_t)$ is a subset of $O(s)$. The proof is that $L_t(S^1)$ has winding number $1$ around $x_t$; but winding number of $L_s(S^1)$ around $x_t$ is continuous as a function $s \in I_t$, and so also equals $1$ for all $s \in I_t$.

The sets $I_t$ form an open covering of $[0,1]$. Choose a Lebesgue number $\lambda$ for this open covering. Let
$$0 = t(0) < t(1) < \cdots < t(K) =1
$$
be a sequence of intervals such that $t(k) - t(k-1) < \lambda$ for $k=1,...,K$.

From the choices, it follows for each $k=1,...,K$ and each $s \in [t(k-1),t(k)]$ that the straight line segment $\overline{x_{t(k-1)},x_{t(k)}}$ is disjoint from $L_s(S^1)$. Thus by concatenating these segments from $k=1$ to $K$ we obtain a piecewise straight path $f(t)$ such that $f(t) \in O(t)$ for each $t \in [0,1]$.